# Draw transparent bitmap on backgound

Tags: android, kotlin, android-graphview

I want to draw transparent bitmaps on a background in a game. However, the bitmap is not transparent, it still has white color in the background. Here is my code

```
inner class Canvass(context: Context) : View(context) {
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val frame_paint: Paint = Paint()
        frame_paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        frame_paint.isAntiAlias = true

        val framegame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (resources, R.drawable.frame)
        canvas.drawBitmap (framegame, 0f, 0f, frame_paint)


        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint)

        val tennis_paint: Paint = Paint()
        tennis_paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        tennis_paint.color = Color.TRANSPARENT
        tennis_paint.isAntiAlias = true

        val tennis = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (resources, R.drawable.tennis_ball)
        canvas.drawBitmap (tennis, 50f, 200f, tennis_paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: how to know where is it ?

Comment: I add implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'

Comment: With that code, if the drawn images have white backgrounds, then your image files have white backgrounds.

Comment: How I fix this problems and what code is right ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that your images don't actually have transparent backgrounds.

Comment: do you know any code to solve this problem ?

Comment: It's not the code. It's your images. They are not actually transparent. Use an image editor to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

I found this code, it works for me.

```
        val tennis_paint: Paint = Paint()
        tennis_paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        tennis_paint.isAntiAlias = true

        val tennis = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (resources, R.drawable.tennis_ball)
        var bitmap = transparent_bitmap(tennis)
        canvas.drawBitmap (bitmap, 50f, 300f, tennis_paint)

 fun transparent_bitmap(bmp:Bitmap):Bitmap{

        var bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bmp.width,
            bmp.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        bitmap.setHasAlpha(true)

        for (x in 1..bmp.width-1){
            for (y in 1..bmp.height-1){
                var pixel = bmp.getPixel(x,y)
                val redValue = Color.red(pixel)
                val blueValue = Color.blue(pixel)
                val greenValue = Color.green(pixel)

                if ((redValue==255)and(blueValue==255)and(greenValue==255)){
                    bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color.argb(1,0,0,0))
                }else {
                    bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color.rgb(redValue,greenValue,blueValue))
                }
            }
        }

        return bitmap
    }
```

Comment: No, don't do this at runtime. You're wasting time and resources. Just edit the images with an image editor to make the backgrounds transparent.